# Gio.VolumeMonitor: get_volumes() not updated?

Tags: python-3.x, pygobject, gobject, mtp, gio

I want to verify that my smartphone is properly connected via USB for file transfer via MTP.

```
from gi.repository import Gio
volume_monitor = Gio.VolumeMonitor.get()
for volume in volume_monitor.get_volumes():
    activation_root = volume.get_activation_root()
    if activation_root:
        if activation_root.get_uri_scheme() == 'mtp':
            print('mtp found: name = {}'.format(volume.get_name()))
```

This script works correctly and sends me back the name of the smartphone if it is connected or nothing otherwise.

But if I do the same thing with a loop as below, the result is always that of the first loop even if I connect or disconnect the smartphone between two loops.

```
from gi.repository import Gio
answer = "y"
while answer=="y":
    volume_monitor = Gio.VolumeMonitor.get()
    for volume in volume_monitor.get_volumes():
        activation_root = volume.get_activation_root()
        if activation_root:
            if activation_root.get_uri_scheme() == 'mtp':
                print('mtp found: name = {}'.format(volume.get_name()))
    answer = input("Retry?")
```

What did I miss?

PS: Identical problem described here: [Module Object Won't Update Until Code is Restarted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60037881/module-object-wont-update-until-code-is-restarted)

---

**Edit** after response from *gianmt*

I have a python script that interacts with the user through [zenity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zenity) dialogs.

I display these different states:

- connection by USB cable: yes / no
- mtp mounted: yes / no
- transfer authorized on the smartphone: yes / no

According to these different possible states, I can guide the user to get *yes* to all these states.

When everything is ok, I offer to run an incremental backup (`rsync` with `--link-dest`) from the smartphone to Debian. I make him wait in front of a zenity progress bar.

To display the different states, I am currently using the `gio` binary of glib by parsing the outputs of:

- `gio mount -li`
- `gio info mtp://smarphone_hostname/`
- `gio info mtp://smarphone_hostname/ | grep filesystem::size`

I wanted to use the following objects and methods:

- `Gio.VolumeMonitor`: `get_volumes()`
- `Gio.Volume`: `get_activation_root()`
- `Gio.File`: `get_path()`, `query_filesystem_info('filesystem :: size')`

Your solution, which I had also considered, works very well. But I don't see how to integrate the glib mainloop into my script.

(Environment: Debian Buster, xfce, libmtp, gvfs-mtp-backend, gvfs-fuse)

Answer (score 0):

You should not use a while loop but you should use the glib mainloop in order to make it work and listen for connections, also your program should listen for the signal emitted in the mainloop, see your script modified here below:

```
from gi.repository import Gio, GLib

main = GLib.MainLoop()

def on_volume_added(monitor, volume):
    print (volume.get_name())

volume_monitor = Gio.VolumeMonitor.get()
volume_monitor.connect("volume-added", on_volume_added)

for volume in volume_monitor.get_volumes():
    activation_root = volume.get_activation_root()
    if activation_root:
        if activation_root.get_uri_scheme() == 'mtp':
            print('mtp found: name = {}'.format(volume.get_name()))

main.run()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.

I added information to my question to clarify the context. I also specify why I do not know how to use your answer.